# how to set background image to TListview in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tlistview

how i can to to set background image to TListview in Delphi XE??

i want to make a application like Windows Explorer.

Comment: explain my  question:
in the my real project i have a TListview and a TButton.
i want to, when click Button1, then set a background image for Listview1 (like windows explorer)
please see picture, in this picture i set a background image for a Folder.
i want to make a app,like this picture : http://www.4shared.com/photo/zvzwuCp_/untitled_2.html

Answer (score 9):

In order to set a watermark in the listview you need to use the [LVM_SETBKIMAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761155%28VS.85%29.aspx) message, and you need to override the TListView's default WM_ERASEBKGND message.  The listview takes ownership of the bitmap handle, so you need to use TBitmap's `ReleaseHandle`, rather than just `Handle`.

If you want it aligned to the top-left, instead of the bottom right like Explorer, use `LVBKIF_SOURCE_HBITMAP` instead of `LVBKIF_TYPE_WATERMARK` for the `ulFlags` value.

```
uses
  CommCtrl, ...;

type
  TListView = class(ComCtrls.TListView)
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
      override;
  end;

  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure TListView.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_ERASEBKGND then
    DefaultHandler(Message)
  else
    inherited WndProc(Message);
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Img: TImage;
  BkImg: TLVBKImage;
begin
  FillChar(BkImg, SizeOf(BkImg), 0);
  BkImg.ulFlags := LVBKIF_TYPE_WATERMARK;
  // Load image and take ownership of the bitmap handle
  Img := TImage.Create(nil);
  try
    Img.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\Watermark.bmp');
    BkImg.hbm := Img.Picture.Bitmap.ReleaseHandle;
  finally
    Img.Free;
  end;
  // Set the watermark
  SendMessage(ListView1.Handle, LVM_SETBKIMAGE, 0, LPARAM(@BkImg));
end;
```

**Stretched Watermark**

The listview doesn't natively support stretching a bitmap across the entire background.  To do so you need to do a StretchBlt in response to WM_ERASEBKGND yourself.

```
type
  TMyListView = class(TListView)
  protected
    procedure CreateHandle; override;
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Msg: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  public
    Watermark: TBitmap;
  end;

procedure TMyListView.CreateHandle;
begin
  inherited;
  // Set text background color to transparent
  SendMessage(Handle, LVM_SETTEXTBKCOLOR, 0, CLR_NONE);
end;

procedure TMyListView.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  // Invalidate every time the listview is resized
  Params.Style := Params.Style or CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW;
end;

procedure TMyListView.WMEraseBkgnd(var Msg: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  StretchBlt(Msg.DC, 0, 0, Width, Height, Watermark.Canvas.Handle,
    0, 0, Watermark.Width, Watermark.Height, SrcCopy);
  Msg.Result := 1;
end;
```

Comment: very thanks. I put your code's in the project, but has error and doesn't work.can you solve it, Please. (http://4shared.com/file/ImTrNd-Z/lvdemo_edited.html
 )

Comment: If you look at the code I posted, "Watermark" is a TBitmap field/property I added to TMyListView.  You need to assign that instead of using LVM_SETBKIMAGE.  LVM_SETBKIMAGE doesn't support stretching, so you can't use it.  Also, it looks like setting the CS_HREDRAW/CS_VREDRAW styles in CreateParams messes up the drawing.  Remove that and manually invalidate it in the ListView's OnResize event handler.

Comment: Also, in the code you posted, you have a TwpListView where you're adding the code, but your types are declared as TListView.  You need to do the aliasing like I did in my first code sample, or create the TwpListView at runtime.  As it is, none of the code in there is getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

a Tlistview is nice but if you want more. i suggess you have to update with [VirtualStringTree(VirtualTreeView)](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=38) very flexible you can customize it almost anything you want and most of all its free.